# Is there a way to get the affected files of a commit with a git post-commit hook?

Tags: git, version-control, hook

I'm using git within a perforce repository. I want to be able to know exactly what files were affected by a git commit so I can turn around with a post-commit hook and open those files for edit in perforce, so the perforce server knows about the changes.
Is there a way I can get a list, within the post-commit hook, of exactly what files were affected by the commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the raw data:

`git diff-tree HEAD`

Comment: Doesn't look like that gets me a list of the actual files - it's showing me the affected directories.

Comment: ...nevermind, digging through the options of diff-tree this may work.

Answer (score 6):

Get the affected paths (relative to `$GIT_DIR`) of the current branch's head with

```
git show --pretty=oneline --name-only HEAD | sed 1d
```

Comment: You can get the exact same output with:
git diff-tree --name-only -r HEAD | sed 1d  

Interesting that there's a few ways to do this...

Comment: In this case, go with `git diff-tree` over `git show` because the former is low-level plumbing, as opposed to porcelain meant for human use. See http://progit.org/book/ch9-1.html

Answer (score 1):

is `git log --name-only` what you're looking for? `git log --name-status` also shows the action like M for modified, A for added (i presume) etc.

Lastly, the option `--pretty=oneline` might be handy for easier parsing.

Obviously you've probably figured this out already but I added this for future reference.